# Navigation adds to url instead of resetting url and going to link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm very new to javascript and was following a tutorial, but ended up experimenting.

In my navigation I have some standard stuff like so:

```
    render() {
        return (
            <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
                <Link to="" className="navbar-brand">House App</Link>
                <Nav className="mr-auto" >
                    <Link to="addHouse" className="nav-link">Add House</Link>
                    <Link to="houses" className="nav-link">Manage Houses</Link>
                    <Link to="addPerson" className="nav-link">Add User</Link>
                    <Link to="people" className="nav-link">Users</Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar>
        );
    }
```

I'm experimenting with trying to bind a person to a house. First there is a userlist where you can click "add person to house", than the url will change to "http://localhost:3000/addPersonToHouse/8" where 8 is the personId. Than if personId is a number (with isNaN) I want it to execute the method "addPersonToHouse(personId, houseId)". My question is not about executing it, but when you click on "add person to house" the url changes and when I click on stuff on the navigation bar it doesn't register and the url changes to, for example, "http://localhost:3000/addPersonToHouse/people". What it's actually supposed to do is "http://localhost:3000/people" how do I do that?

Comment: Include the framework you are using in your "tags" and question

Comment: put `/` at the beginning of them. You might want to read about relative vs absolute path by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Link to="/addHouse" className="nav-link">Add House</Link>
```

`/addHouse` absolute routing; this will replace the [pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) of url with `/addHouse`.

but you are adding something to end of current url by using `./addHouse` ( i.e. relative routing )